Cox Regression: handling immediate drop-outs
In an RCT with two groups, I‘m currently analyzing data using cox regression. While I‘m familiar with the concept of censoring, a rather substantial amount of participants (~32% and 35% in the groups) did not show up at any further follow-up, so I do not have any data for these participants after randomization. I‘m struggling on how to deal with such data and am currently thinking about three possible solutions:

censoring at time=0 and Event=0,
complete case analysis,
MI (though rarely recommended for Outcome data).

For censoring at time=0, I did not see many papers, however, this study seems to censor some participants directly at time=0 (see figure2).
For the latter (MI) I couldn't find any papers on how to deal with such missing outcome data, while many papers on missing covariates exist.
Are there any guidelines on how to handle such data? Which of the 3 approaches mentioned would be preferred or are there other ways?

The number of patients who are censored is irrelevant to the analysis. That is to say, the number of clinical events truly drives the comparisons, whether death or disease progression or clinical response, whatever. Successful calculation and analysis of a Cox model relies upon having a truly prospective study, no future event (whether censoring or otherwise) should modify any representation of the data at an earlier time.
Options 1 and 2 that you have proposed are essentially the same, and both will result in a biased analysis if certain assumptions are not met. In cancer studies, for instance, cancer scans are performed periodically to detect if the disease has progressed. Of course, if the disease is found to progress at a certain scan time, this event is subject to interval censoring - we do not know at which exact time the cancer was found to have progressed. As such, we use the timing of the scan as the actual event time, but we otherwise censor patients at their last available scan - even if this means censoring patients with no available scan after treatment at study day 1 (i.e. they are excluded from analysis). It is not uncommon in studies like this to recruit several hundred participants so that we can ensure only maybe 30% of them experience a clinical event - the remainder of the participants are censored.
Option 3 can be considered a type of per-protocol analysis - that is what might have been a patient's outcome had they remained on study. This is an especially useful tool when data are missing not at random, and certain model-based procedures can be used to consider their outcomes. Fitting these models is highly complex and involves extensive external data collection, surrogate marker analysis within the study population, and consultation with statistical and clinical experts - and even then, is at best only a "sensitivity analysis" to corroborate primary, prespecified analyses.
The only possible exception to this rule may lie in how you have prespecified and intent-to-treat analysis versus a per-protocol analysis. These considerations usually have to do with identifying difference in the method efficacy of drug product versus its use efficacy. We might require for instance that a dose intensity meets a certain criterion to include subjects in analysis, and this usually excludes subjects with limited participation. However, in the RCT setting, the ITT analysis is king, because it is not preferrable to have to condition on one's perfect compliance with a treatment to ensure its efficacy - you may in fact show us that they are a healthy group of compliant people who received an ineffective drug.
